# Print to standard output in SML

Tags: sml

```
datatype term = node of string*term list
         | vnode of string
```

I have a value of type **term**. How do I print it in SML to the standard output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to first create a string out of the `term` and then print that using `print`. To turn a `term` into a string, you could define a function like this:

```
fun termToString (node (str, terms)) =
    "node(" ^ str ^ ", " ^ termListToString terms ^ ")"
  | termToString (vnode str) =
    "vnode(" ^ str ^ ")"
and termListToString terms =
    "[" ^ String.concatWith ", " (map termToString terms) ^ "]"
```